# Decrease fontsize in Sublime even more

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Sometimes I want the font in Sublime Text (3, build 3083) to be even smaller. For example, when copy/pasting large slabs of code, and determine which part is relevant and which is not. The sidebar isn't helpful, because I cannot read from there (it is *too* small). I can't decrease fontsize any more with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ scroll wheel down. Is there any way to decrease the fontsize even more?

Comment: Manually set it in your user settings?

Comment: That works, but how can I make it last? For example, if I set fontsize to 7 and save, it is indeed small enough. But when I make it back to normal, I cannot go back to fontsize 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change font size from the user settings configuration file, follow the [official Sublime Text documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/font.html).